# Navbar-brand with two lines of text, centered vertically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a Bootstrap navbar with text in the navbar-brand.

I want to have the navbar-brand in two lines of text and both centered vertically, but I only achieve the first line centered vertically, not both...

Below goes a Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Naima/qksxkw1e/

```
<header>
    <nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top' role='navigation'>
        <div class='container-fluid'>
            <div class='navbar-header'>
                <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#collapse'>
                    <span class='sr-only'>Toogle navigation</span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
             </div>
             <div class='navbar-brand'><span class='navbar-title'>Title<br>This is the subtitle</span>
             </div>
            <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='collapse'>
                    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
                    <li><a href='#featured'>Example 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#bla'>Example 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#blabla'>Example 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: You need to supply some code or a fiddle

Comment: Can you show us an example output?

Comment: There's a fiddle in the question

Comment: If you want both lines centered vertically, wouldn't that mean that the brand should be centered, not the lines individually? Also, the fiddle you added lacks jQuery, so it does not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The short way to achieve the wanted effect on the given configuration is to use css transforms like this:

```css
.navbar-brand {
  -ms-transform: translateY(-35px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-35px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-35px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-35px);
  transform: translateY(-35px);
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  header .navbar-default {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    -ms-transform: translateY(-7px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-7px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-7px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-7px);
    transform: translateY(-7px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top' role='navigation'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <div class='navbar-header'>
        <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#collapse'> <span class='sr-only'>Toogle navigation</span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>

      </div>
      <div class='navbar-brand'><span class='navbar-title'>Title<br>This is the subtitle</span>

      </div>
      <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='collapse'>
        <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
          <li><a href='#featured'>Home</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href='#download'>Download</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href='#order'>Order</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

If you need something else, comment. If it helps, +1.